# C# How to display a value from Mysql database to a label?

Tags: c#, mysql, label

I'm doing a login form in Visual Studio in which the users can login and when they do, their position(e.g Admin or User) will be displayed on a label(lblPosition) and when i run the program the error is my syntax is not correct. BTW my database consists of 3 columns name,username,password and Position.I don't really know how to format text here so.. hope you guys can help me;)

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT *  WHERE Username='" + txtboxUsername.Text + "' and Password= '" + txtboxPassword.Text + "'", connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader;
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable ft = new System.Data.DataTable();
                no.Fill(ft);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lblPosition.Text = ft.Rows[1]["Position"].ToString();
                    panelLogin.Hide();
                    panel1.Show();
                }
```

Comment: You haven't stated which table to pull all the columns from.

Comment: You're missing a "FROM" and table name in your SQL statement - "SELECT * FROM tablename...". Also, it's best practice to avoid concatenating SQL strings like that - look into using parameterised queries instead to help avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What is the line no.fill(ft); trying to do?

Comment: Oh the no.fill(ft); is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select query syntax:

```
select * from <table_name> where <condition>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// change the mysql command - you are missing the "FROM" clause in your mysql command 
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM WHERE Username='" + txtboxUsername.Text + "' and Password= '" + txtboxPassword.Text + "'", connection);
                    MySqlDataReader reader;
                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable ft = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    no.Fill(ft);
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lblPosition.Text = ft.Rows[1]["Position"].ToString();
                        panelLogin.Hide();
                        panel1.Show();
                    }
```